# How do I redirect the number of rows after a search?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show the number of search results if there are and if not, I want to show a message that there are no results for your search

**controller**

```
 public function search(Request $request){
        $search = $request->get('search');
        $Airline['Airlines'] = DB::table('airlines')->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(id,' ',name,' ',country)"),'LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(4);
        $count = count($Airline);
        if ($count>0) {
         return redirect()->view('admin.airline',$Airline,)->with('success',$count.' records found');

        }
        else{
            return redirect()->view('admin.airline',$Airline)->with('error','No record found');
        }
        
    }
```

**airline.blade.php**

```
             @if(session()->has('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ session()->get('success') }}
                </div>
            @endif
            @if(session()->has('error'))
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ session()->get('error') }}
                </div>
            @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of rows in blade with:

```
{{ $Airline->count() }}
```

Or simply pass count to blade by controller:

```
return redirect()->view('admin.airline', [
    'Airline' => $Airline,
    'count' => $count
)
```